# change state of clicked target inside mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to change the state inside a map array. my state is shared in all the items created by the map array and I'm trying to change the state of the clicked item, here's the code:

```
{dbData ?
            dbData.map((item, i) => (
                <Box id={item.id} className={`${cl.FolderStyles} ${activeFolderStyles}`} key={i} onClick={activeFolder}>
                    <FolderIcon className={cl.folder_icon} />
                    {item.name}
                </Box>
            ))
            : <img src={loader} alt="loader" />
        }
```

here you can see im creating multiple items, and the state is: "activeFolderStyles",
what i want is to add a class to the clicked item which becomes active but my problem is that the state of all the items is changed after clicking and all become active.

```
            const [activeFolderStyles, setActiveFolderStyles] = useState();
          const activeFolder = (e) => {
            const id = e.target.id;
            const element = document.getElementById(id);
            console.log(element);
            if (element.classList.contains(side_cl.folderActive)) {
              setActiveFolderStyles("");
            }
            else {
              setActiveFolderStyles(side_cl.folderActive);
            }
          }
```

here is the state that im using.

```
 const [activeFolderStyles, setActiveFolderStyles] = useState();
  const activeFolder = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element.classList.contains(side_cl.folderActive)) {
      setActiveFolderStyles("");
    }
    else {
      setActiveFolderStyles(side_cl.folderActive);
    }
```

}

So i dont really know how to point out the targeted state and not all

Comment: If you click on one folder (ie: Box) it becomes active, if you click on another folder/box, should the first folder/box you clicked no longer be active, or can you have multiple folders/boxs set as active at one time?

Comment: only one folder can be active at a time and the rest should get deactivated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain some state that defines what the currently active folder is. The state will identify the currently active folder using its `id`, which can be obtained when you map `dbData`. While mapping, you can check if the current `item.id` of the current `item` is equal the active `id` in your state, and if it is, add your class, otherwise, don't add the class at all (note, `activeFolder` in the below JSX refers to the new state value we're creating to keep track of the active folder id, not your click event handler function from your question):

```js
{dbData ?
  dbData.map((item, i) => (
    <Box id={item.id} className={`${cl.FolderStyles} ${item.id === activeFolder ? side_cl.folderActive : ""}`} key={item.id} onClick={() => handleFolderClick(item.id)}>
      <FolderIcon className={cl.folder_icon} />
      {item.name}
    </Box>
   ))
   : <img src={loader} alt="loader" />
}
```

Then you can create your `activeFolder` state:

```js
const [activeFolder, setActiveFolder] = useState();
```

You can then update this state when you click your folder to the current folder:

```js
// Use this instead of your `activeFolder` function
const handleFolderClick = (newItemId) => {
  // If the folder we're activating is already "active", deactivate it, otherwise, update the state to point to activate our new folder
  setActiveFolder(currItemId => currItemId === newItemId ? "" : newItemId);
}
```

The above JSX uses the above `handleFolderClick` function by passing through the item id of the box that was clicked.

Side note: DOM methods like `getElementById()`, `querySelectorAll()` etc. are rarely ever used in React, if you find yourself using them then there is a good chance that you're not doing something in the way it was intended, where a component's state should be used to help drive the component logic and what it renders.

Comment: hello, is there a way to modify this code for selecting multiple active folders when we hold ctrl key ?

Comment: @amir yes, you can make `activeFolder` an array, and then add your item ids to that array when you're holding ctrl. If you're not holding control, replace the current array with a new array containing just the item you clicked on. You would also need to update the `item.id === activeFolder` check in the JSX to check if your state array contains the current item id (eg: by using `.includes()`)

Comment: thank you, i changed it the way you showed:         
if (e.ctrlKey) {
      setActiveFile(activeFile.concat(newItemId));
      console.log(activeFile);
    }else{
      setActiveFile((currItemId) => (currItemId.includes(newItemId) ? [] : activeFile.concat(newItemId)));
      console.log("ctrl not holded: ",activeFile);
    }
                    but the problem is, on the first click the array is empty and the id is set on the second click, what should i do ?   and here is the state const [activeFile, setActiveFile] = useState([]);

Comment: @amir The array should be being set on your first click. Using `setActiveFile()` doesn't change your state immediately, so using `console.log()` right after you set your state won't show the new state. It's only in the next rerender where your `activeFile` state value will have the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a much cleaner way like so

```
<Box id={item.id} className={item.id === activeFolderStyles ? "ACTIVE CLASSNAME" : "NOT ACTIVE CLASSNAME"} key=. 
   {i} onClick={setActiveFolderStyles(item.id)}>
   <FolderIcon className={cl.folder_icon} />
   {item.name}
</Box>
```